# При нажатии на radiobutton html показать значение value

Tags: javascript, html

Например такой код. Нажал на какой-нибудь radio и вывелось value через alert.

```html
<form>
  <p><b>Какое у вас состояние разума?</b></p>
  <p><input  type="radio" value="nedzen"> Не дзен</p>
  <p><input  type="radio" value="dzen"> Дзен</p>
  <p><input  type="radio" value="pdzen"> Полный дзен</p>
</form> 

<form>
  <p><b>Какое у вас состояние разума?</b></p>
  <p><input name="dzen" type="radio" value="nedzen"> Не дзен</p>
  <p><input name="dzen" type="radio" value="dzen"> Дзен</p>
  <p><input name="dzen" type="radio" value="pdzen"> Полный дзен</p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если JQuery то:

```
 $('input[type=radio][name=dzen]').change(function() {
    alert(this.value);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Если ориентрироваться на ваш HTML, то вот так:

```js
const inputArr = document.querySelectorAll('input');
inputArr.forEach((input) => {
        input.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        alert(e.target.value);
    });
})
```

```html
<form>
    <p><b>Какое у вас состояние разума?</b></p>
    <p><input  type="radio" value="nedzen"> Не дзен</p>
    <p><input  type="radio" value="dzen"> Дзен</p>
    <p><input  type="radio" value="pdzen"> Полный дзен</p>
</form> 

<form>
    <p><b>Какое у вас состояние разума?</b></p>
    <p><input name="dzen" type="radio" value="nedzen"> Не дзен</p>
    <p><input name="dzen" type="radio" value="dzen"> Дзен</p>
    <p><input name="dzen" type="radio" value="pdzen"> Полный дзен</p>
</form>
```

В старом стандарте `ES5` код будет таким:

```
'use strict';

var inputArr = document.querySelectorAll('input');
inputArr.forEach(function (input) {
  input.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    alert(e.target.value);
  });
});
```

Если JQuery, то код будет таким:

```js
$('input').each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function() {
        alert($(this).val())
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <p><b>Какое у вас состояние разума?</b></p>
    <p><input  type="radio" value="nedzen"> Не дзен</p>
    <p><input  type="radio" value="dzen"> Дзен</p>
    <p><input  type="radio" value="pdzen"> Полный дзен</p>
</form> 

<form>
    <p><b>Какое у вас состояние разума?</b></p>
    <p><input name="dzen" type="radio" value="nedzen"> Не дзен</p>
    <p><input name="dzen" type="radio" value="dzen"> Дзен</p>
    <p><input name="dzen" type="radio" value="pdzen"> Полный дзен</p>
</form>
```

А если писать по хорошему, то у вас должны быть `label`, внутри которых лежат `input`. В вашем примере клик происходит только по самому `input`, но не по тексту рядом. Ниже пример вашего кода через `label`

```js
const labels = document.querySelectorAll('label');

labels.forEach((label) => {
    label.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        const input = label.querySelector('input');
        const value = input.value;
            
        input.checked = true;
        e.preventDefault();
        alert(value);
    });
});
```

```html
<p><b>Какое у вас состояние разума?</b></p>
<p>
  <label for="nedzen">
     <input id="nedzen" name="dzen" type="radio" value="nedzen" checked> 
     Не дзен
   </label>
    </p>
<p>
  <label for="dzen">
     <input id="dzen" name="dzen" type="radio" value="dzen">
     Дзен
  </label>
</p>
<p>
  <label for="fulldzen">
     <input id="fulldzen" name="dzen" type="radio" value="pdzen">
     Полный дзен
  </label>
</p>
```

Если нужен старый стандарт `ES5`, то выглядеть код будет так:

```
'use strict';

var labels = document.querySelectorAll('label');

labels.forEach(function (label) {
    label.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        var input = label.querySelector('input');
        var value = input.value;

        input.checked = true;
        e.preventDefault();
        alert(value);
    });
});
```